# Data validation restricting other numbering formats except the given one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My numbering format is `00-000` where **00**(left) must not be less than 1 or greater than 12 while **000**(right) can be infinite. Also a dash (-) must be present in between both numbers. I want to put restriction through *data validation* so that when anyone tries to insert any other numbers than the given format it should give error.

Comment: that's great - what did you try and where can we help? please provide a minimal example of your code...

Comment: This is actually a string right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add custom formula for data validation and try something like (where replace H4 with you cell to add validation to).Pretty sure you can simplify this.

```
=AND(FIND("-",H4,1)=3,1*LEFT(H4,FIND("-",H4,1)-1)<13,1*LEFT(H4,FIND("-",H4,1)-1)>=1,ISNUMBER(1*RIGHT(H4,LEN(H4)-FIND("-",H4,1))))
```